# Gradle sync failed: removeContentEntry: removed content entry url '...' still exists after removing

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a gradle sync fail for my little project that seems to be quite rare as google did not find anything about it. I get the error:
`Gradle sync failed: removeContentEntry: removed content entry url 'file://C:/Users/BenutzerA/IdeaProjects/EtikettenScanner1/app' still exists after removing (2 s 337 ms)`

A clean build did not help. "Invalidate caches /Restart" did not help.
So far this seems the only project that suffers from this problem. I switched to 3 other projects and they all build without problems.

Project uses Kotlin, Android, Google-Services

Anyone has a hint for me?

Part of idea.log:

````
021-02-15 20:39:10,076 [4053612]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - removeContentEntry: removed content entry url 'file://C:/Users/BenutzerA/IdeaProjects/EtikettenScanner1/app' still exists after removing 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: removeContentEntry: removed content entry url 'file://C:/Users/BenutzerA/IdeaProjects/EtikettenScanner1/app' still exists after removing
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.roots.ModifiableRootModelBridgeImpl.removeContentEntry(ModifiableRootModelBridgeImpl.kt:209)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.common.ContentEntriesSetup.removeExistingContentEntries(ContentEntriesSetup.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.ndk.NdkModuleCleanupStep.cleanUpModule(NdkModuleCleanupStep.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.NdkModuleModelDataService.onModelNotFound(NdkModuleModelDataService.java:78)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.ModuleModelDataService.onModelsNotFound(ModuleModelDataService.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.ModuleModelDataService.importData(ModuleModelDataService.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.doImportData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:206)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask.doPopulateProject(ProjectSetUpTask.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask.onSuccess(ProjectSetUpTask.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.handExecutionResult(ExternalSystemUtil.java:559)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:539)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:185)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:644)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:962)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:472)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)```
````

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Have you tried to remove all IDE related data (.iml file and .idea folder) and reimport project?

Comment: @y.bedrov Removing those files helped me to solve the problem, it works fine now, thank you very much. I will remember that for the future! 
My IDE-version: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-203.7148.57, built on January 26, 2021

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I am facing the same cryptic error message.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-294971/Gradle-composite-project-reload-error-removeContentEntry-removed-content-entry-url-file-monorepo for the open bug that is going nowhere.

Answer (score 29):

Intellij Idea 2022.1.4 (Ultimate edition)

My solution is to delete files:

- project-dir/.idea/compiler.xml
- project-dir/.idea/modules.xml

restart/reload the Gradle project

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 
Didn't find the `modules.xml`, however removing `gradle.xml` helped

Comment: remove .idea file helped

Comment: solution worked fine ✅

Answer (score 21):

1. Remove ".idea" folder.
2. Reopen the project. The problem should be gone.
3. Restore the previously deleted ".idea" folder.

Comment: Worked for me (but I skipped step 3). I tried the other solutions by just removing the `.xml` from the `.idea` folder but it didn't work. I'm on Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1. With gradle 7.4 and AGP 7.3.1

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you miss it in the initial comments, when I had this problem (in another project using IntelliJ IDEA directly) removing the .iml file and the .idea directory and re importing the project worked like a treat for me.

Comment: yes, just deleting/renaming .idea folder (just restarting IDE) worked for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Delete ".idea" folder. Helps already twice for me, IDEA 2022.1.4 Ultimate

Comment: Same, deleting `.idea` and reimporting with gradle (automatically detected by intellij) worked for me

Comment: In the end this is the only thing, that actually helped. Restarting, invalidating caches did not, didn't want to change the IntelliJ version and there was no `<content .../>` in my `*.iml` files. So deleting the `.idea` folder altogether resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to remove a duplicate entry in .idea/modules/myproject.test.iml
this entry was duplicated :

```
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test" isTestSource="true" generated="true" />
</content>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is solution helped me:

- Build needle build variant via terminal (./gradlew assembleRelease for example)
- After change build  variant to needle via android studio  (to Release in this example)
  May be it helps other people

Comment: After running "gradlew assembleRelease" with success, still no Build Variants are displayed and project sync still fails with same error. In my case the folder it is trying to release is a CMake project folder checked out from git that should not be removed anyway. Anyone knows why gradle is trying to delete projects in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like this:

1. Export project to a `zip` file
2. Delete old folder (make a backup)
3. Unzip the exported project
4. Run Android Studio again from that folder

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I use is to Invalidate Caches and restart.
After the restart the project syncs again without the error.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

No answer was of help to me. Neither repairing the IDE, removing all the build directories, etc. Until I tried with a different version of Android Studio.

So, my suggestion, try opening the project with a different version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, click on *File* -> *Invalidate Caches...* -> *Invalidate and Restart*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to simply rename the folder that contained the Android Studio project. Actually, the first thing I did was just checkout my code from the git repo into a different folder. The code was exactly the same as the original folder causing me this issue. So if we say that my original folder was called X, I then renamed the "bad" folder to "X.BAD" and renamed the new "good" folder to X. After swapping them I noticed that the fresh checkout of the code sitting in the folder named X now has this problem, but the project in X.BAD works just fine.

So somehow AndroidStudio must keep some information about these projects outside of the actual project folder. Clearly this is an AndroidStudio bug. I created a bug report. If people are experiencing this, please go visit and let them know about it. Thanks.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/320857594

NOTE: This is on AndroidStudio 2023.1.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was very complicated. Deleting (project).iml and .idea (and .gradle), repairing IDE and even invalidating caches did not work. Then I restored the .idea directory from git, removed all files except the "modules.xml" and the "modules" subfolder - first from the repository, then locally - and restarted the IDE. It reported a lot of errors, I had to restart it again, but finally I could rebuild the project. (It's funny that the modules.xml file and modules subfolder are gone after rebuild) -  Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1

Answer (score -1):

If you have been upgraded to the new version of Android Studio, We should go back to the old version.

Comment: Seriously? This worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked in my situation. I try to another way so clean the cache, and validate,... But they do not help me. After that, I try to download a different Android Studio and It works perfectly.

Comment: I initially downvoted, but actually, if you are using jellyfish, it seems to be broken. Just use iguana. I literally downgraded to iguana and the project imported successfully immediately.