# gradle sync failed : removeContentEntry: removed content entry url <path> still exists after removing

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm getting a Gradle sync failed error to my web service project, I've already tried "Invalidate caches /Restart" and it did not help.

The error seems like this, `removeContentEntry: removed content entry URL 'file://.../build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main' still exists after removing`

That seems to be quite rare, Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: Does it work Fien from command line?

Comment: I sometimes get a similar issue. I deleted all the build related folders/files and restarted Android Studio - seemed to finally do the trick.

Comment: I get same error in Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526, built on July 10, 2022

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214555/gradle-sync-failed-removecontententry-removed-content-entry-url-still-ex (not that there is a really an answer there either)